# Ref/DeRef a double pointed link list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, double-pointer

I'm passing a linked-list, containing another linked-list to a function but I am having problems de/referencing the internal linked list from the double pointer passed.  The Compiler error here for the line `push(*config->inner_linked_list...` is `'*config' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'`. Inside main `&config->inner_linked_list` works fine. I cant seem to work out what sort of ref/deref I would need to use here.

```
typedef struct new_inner {
    wchar_t setting[10];
    wchar_t val[10];
    struct new_inner  * next;
}INTLL_t ;

typedef struct new_head {
    wchar_t name[10];
    struct INTLL_t * inner_linked_list;
    struct new_head * next;
} HEAD_t;




// In Main
int main(){
...
    HEAD_t * config;
    config = malloc(sizeof(HEAD_t));
    config = NULL;

//config populated elsewhere

    functo1(&config);
...
}


BOOL functo1(HEAD_t ** config){
    HEAD_t * current = *config;
    while(current != NULL){

    INTLL_t * s = another_ll; // Also INTLL_t
    while(s != NULL){


    push(*config->inner_linked_list, another_ll->setting,another_ll->val);
            s = s->next;
    }

    current = current->next;
}

return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: `config = malloc(sizeof(NODE_t));` did you mean `sizeof(HEAD_t)`? `NODE_t` is not defined in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member access through pointer operator -> has higher priority than dereference operator * so when you do *config->inner_linked_list it tries to access a member of double pointer of HEAD_t which will result in an error. It works in main because there the config object is a normal pointer. You need parentheses for correct usage.

> (*config)->inner_linked_list

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

```
    struct INTLL_t * inner_linked_list;
```

`struct INTLL_t` is an undefined type. It's unrelated to `INTLL_t` (which is a typedef, not a struct). You probably meant either `INTLL_t *` or `struct new_inner *` here.

```
    HEAD_t * config;
    config = malloc(sizeof(NODE_t));
    config = NULL;
```

This is a memory leak. You've just lost the only pointer to the block returned by `malloc`. Also, `NODE_t` is not defined. In any case, it should be `config = malloc(sizeof (HEAD_t))` or (preferably) `config = malloc(sizeof *config)`.

```
BOOL functo1(HEAD_t ** config){
```

`BOOL` is not defined.

```
    NODE_t * s = another_ll;
```

Neither `NODE_t` nor `another_ll` are defined.

```
    push(*config->inner_linked_list, another_ll->setting,another_ll->val);
```

`push` is not defined.

`config` is a pointer to a pointer to a struct. `*a->b` parses as `*(a->b)`, which requires `a` to be a pointer to a struct whose `b` member is also a pointer (it's equivalent to `*((*a).b)`). You want `(*config)->inner_linked_list` instead (or equivalently `(**config).inner_linked_list`).

```
return TRUE;
```

`TRUE` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the response and your time.

Comment: I've been trying to workout the logic of the memory leak here.
Is it due to executing sizeof(NODE_t) and because NODE_t is undefined.
(* NODE_t was a typo. should have been HEAD_t)

or
Is setting "config = NULL" after the malloc call not doing what i think it does?